# Zend Error In MySQL Connection Netbeans

Tags: database, netbeans, zend-framework, database-connection

I have a problem after revert my three code files from local history supported by Netbeans, which I did by copy everything from pre-modified file to current file. But, when I run it, the page showed white screen with this error warning :

```
object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception)#17 (9) { ["_chainedException":protected]=> NULL
["_previous":"Zend_Exception":private]=> NULL ["message":protected]=> string(86) 
"SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: 
YES)" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> int(1045) 
["file":protected]=> string(53) "/var/www/erp/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php" 
["line":protected]=> int(144) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(8) { [0]=> array(6) 
{ ["file"]=> string(50) "/var/www/erp/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php" ["line"]=> 
int(96) ["function"]=> string(8) "_connect" ["class"]=> string(28) "Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract" 
["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(0) { } } [1]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(49) 
"/var/www/erp/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php" ["line"]=> int(304) ["function"]=> string(8)
"_connect" ["class"]=> string(25) "Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" 
["args"]=> array(0) { } } [2]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(38) "/var/www/erp/application/Bootstrap.php" 
["line"]=> int(116) ["function"]=> string(13) "getConnection" ["class"]=> string(24) 
"Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(0) { } } [3]=> 
array(6) { ["file"]=> string(69) "/var/www/erp/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php" 
["line"]=> int(665) ["function"]=> string(15) "_initConnection" ["class"]=> 
string(9) "Bootstrap" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(0) { } } [4]=> array(6) 
{ ["file"]=> string(69) "/var/www/erp/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php" 
["line"]=> int(618) ["function"]=> string(16) "_executeResource" ["class"]=> 
string(44) "Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" 
["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> &string(10) "connection" } } [5]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> 
string(69) "/var/www/erp/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php" 
["line"]=> int(582) ["function"]=> string(10) "_bootstrap" ["class"]=> string(44) 
"Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> 
array(1) { [0]=> &NULL } } [6]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(41) "/var/www/erp/library/Zend/Application.php" 
["line"]=> int(355) ["function"]=> string(9) "bootstrap" ["class"]=> string(44) 
"Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(1) 
{ [0]=> &NULL } } [7]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(29) "/var/www/erp/public/index.php" 
["line"]=> int(28) ["function"]=> string(9) "bootstrap" ["class"]=> string(16) 
"Zend_Application" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(0) { } } } ["previous":"Exception":private]=> 
object(PDOException)#19 (8) {    ["message":protected]=> string(86) "SQLSTATE[28000] 
[1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)" ["string":"Exception":private]=> 
string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> int(1045) ["file":protected]=> string(53) 
"/var/www/erp/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php" ["line":protected]=> 
int(129) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(9) { [0]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> 
string(53) "/var/www/erp/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php" ["line"]=> 
int(129) ["function"]=> string(11) "__construct" ["class"]=> string(3) "PDO" ["type"]=> 
string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(43) "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=erpdb;port=3306" 
[1]=> string(4) "root" [2]=> string(4) "root" [3]=> array(0) { } } } [1]=> array(6) { 
["file"]=> string(50) "/var/www/erp/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php" ["line"]=> 
int(96) ["function"]=> string(8) "_connect" ["class"]=> string(28) "Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract" 
["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(0) { } } [2]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(49) 
"/var/www/erp/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php" ["line"]=> int(304) ["function"]=> 
string(8) "_connect" ["class"]=> string(25) "Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql" ["type"]=> 
string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(0) { } } [3]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(38) 
"/var/www/erp/application/Bootstrap.php" ["line"]=> int(116) ["function"]=> 
string(13) "getConnection" ["class"]=> string(24) "Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract" 
["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(0) { } } [4]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> 
string(69) "/var/www/erp/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php" 
["line"]=> int(665) ["function"]=> string(15) "_initConnection" ["class"]=> 
string(9) "Bootstrap" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(0) { } } [5]=> array(6) 
{ ["file"]=> string(69) "/var/www/erp/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php" 
["line"]=> int(618) ["function"]=> string(16) "_executeResource" ["class"]=> 
string(44) "Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" 
["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> &string(10) "connection" } } [6]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> 
string(69) "/var/www/erp/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php" 
["line"]=> int(582) ["function"]=> string(10) "_bootstrap" ["class"]=> string(44) 
"Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> 
array(1) { [0]=> &NULL } } [7]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(41) "/var/www/erp/library/Zend/Application.php" 
["line"]=> int(355) ["function"]=> string(9) "bootstrap" ["class"]=> string(44) 
"Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> 
array(1) { [0]=> &NULL } } [8]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(29) "/var/www/erp/public/index.php" 
["line"]=> int(28) ["function"]=> string(9) "bootstrap" ["class"]=> string(16) 
"Zend_Application" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(0) { } } } ["previous":"Exception":private]=> 
NULL ["errorInfo"]=> NULL } } Error in MySQL Connection
```

How to deal with this error? What I can get is there is some trouble with database connection, but no further that that. Any help appreciated.

Comment: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1''. Seems you need to fix that.

Comment: I did SELECT `User`, `Grant_priv` FROM `mysql`.`user` WHERE `User` = 'root' in my database and all the grant_priv is Y @pvg